# CompositeResult.Queries().Add() is not working

Tags: force.com-toolkit-for-net

I am using force.com-toolkit for .Net and I am trying to create a mock Composite Result for my unit tests. Below is the code snippet:

```
var result = new CompositeResult();
var queryResult1 = new QueryResult<JObject> { Done = true, TotalSize = 1, Records = new List<JObject> { new() { { "Value__c", 2 } } } };
result.Queries().Add("queryTabConfiguration", queryResult1);
```

When I am trying to check the **result** value, it is showing empty records although as per above code I added a query result object to result.